# How to check if a column for a number of rows contains a value in Excel

Tags: excel

My data looks like this:

```
A          B
bla        
bla        Yes
boe        Yes
boe        Yes
bal    
bal
```

I want to check for every value in column A whether it has a "yes" in column B. I don't care how often it has a "yes", just whether is has a "yes" or not.

So I'd like to get the following result:

```
bla: Yes 
boe: Yes
bal: No
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pivot table? Isn't that enough?

Comment: And where do you want the result ? as a other table or VBA ? and your result also has No in it so do you want to check if No and Yes is in colum B ?

Comment: Use a Pivot Table with Number Formatting to display `Yes` or `No` if the Count is >0 or not.  You may have to choose to display the results as a percentage of the total in order to "force" a zero into the zero counts.